# how to Insert a key data and information of the table where it belong to, So that it can be searched using the key data in that table. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Multiple table that contains rows in it.

I have to make a table that contains id of a particular row, Tag Name and from which table that id belongs to so that if I want to search a tag I will get results of rows present in the multiple tables.

eg:
**table 1**

```
id | name | column 1
 1 | A    | ..
 2 | B    | ..
 3 | C    | ..
```

**table 2**

```
id | name | column 1 | column 2
 1 | D    | ..       | ..
 2 | E    | ..       | ..
 3 | F    | ..       | ..
```

**table 3**

```
id | name
 1 | G
 2 | H
 3 | I
```

above tables are those multiple tables that contains data in it.

**Tag Table**

```
Student Id | Tags     | From which table it belongs to
1          | Good Boy | Table 1
1          | Good Boy | Table 2
3          | Good Boy | Table 1
2          | Bad Boy  | Table 1
1          | Bad Boy  | Table 3
```

If I want to retrieve data of good boys.

**Expected Output**

```
Id | name
1 | A
1 | D
3 | C
```

Please tell me a way to insert data like this so that if I can search data of good boys or bad boys.

Comment: FYI: [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What are these 3 tables supposed to represent? Are they different types of data? It's all a bit abstract, but I smell some sort of denormalisation occurring.

Comment: @ADyson I Cannot tamper with those 3 tables, I only have to make that tag table.

Comment: Why not? But please at least explain what they represent then we have the context. The fact you're contemplating storing a column which contains the name of another table to search in strongly suggests a design flaw.

Comment: those 3 tables have different number of columns that contains some data.

Comment: That clearly doesn't explain anything, which I think you must realise. "some columns with some data in it"...yes well, it's a database table, so obviously. I asked what do they _represent_, logically? It _seems_ like you have multiple different lists of students in different tables, which does not make much sense. But maybe I misunderstood because we have no clarity about the data model.

Comment: You may be right, but I cannot do anything about those 3 tables.

Comment: Ok. But if we understand the nature and purpose of them better, it would likely be easier to help you find a workable solution. I don't know why you don't just give a more detailed explanation of them instead of keep repeating the same thing you already told me. I am tired of repeatedly asking!! :-) `I have Multiple table that contains rows in it.`...rows of what? students? cats? fridges? bowling alleys?

Comment: `I cannot do anything about those 3 tables`...you also never explained why you can't. Anything can be changed, given enough time / willpower / resources.

Comment: Where does `1 | D` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would store the data from all three tables in a single table, with another column for `BelongsTo`.

You can manufacture this by unioning all the tables together, then you simply join on the result.

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.Name
FROM Tag
JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.Name, 'Table1' BelongsTo
    FROM table1 t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.Name, 'Table2'
    FROM table2 t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.Name, 'Table3'
    FROM table3 t
) t ON t.id = Tag.StudentId AND Tag.BelongsTo = t.BelongsTo
WHERE Tag.Tags = 'Good Boy';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1461915350697de329c833cdca63f4cb)